Building an ES6 library with webpack
I'm looking for something like html-webpack-plugin, but instead of HTML, it will output to a javascript file that loads everything else. I've found js-entry-webpack-plugin, but it doesn't output anything for me, and doesn't seem to spit out any helpful logging that tells me why. Is there anything else, built-in or otherwise, that will do this for me?
Background
I have a project that I want to build into a library (think underscore or jquery) that can be imported dynamically in a browser with ES6. The library's API is very simple, something like
// index.js:
export const MyAPI = {
    function1: <does stuff>,
    function2: <does other stuff>
}

So importing it should be a breeze, but I want to publish it CDN-style, so have to import dynamically:
// example.js:
const { MyAPI } = await import(<url to MyAPI.js>)

I've made the changes in my webpack.config.js to output to a library:
// webpack.config.js:
    experiments: {
      outputModule: true
    },
    output: {
      filename: 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      publicPath: '/',
      chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js',
      assetModuleFilename: ({ filename }) => {
        return filename.endsWith('.css') ? 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css' : 'static/media/[name].[hash][ext]'
      },
      library: {
        type: 'module'
      }
    }

The project produces dozens of js chunks, and when I use html-webpack-plugin, I get an HTML file with an awful lot of  tags. What I'm looking for is a tool that will construct a javascript file that looks something like this. Note that MyAPI is the only interface that needs to be visible outside of the project.
// MyAPI.js
import { a, b, c } from 'main.d7791ce7'
import { d, e, f } from '2.62a7f06e'
import { g, h, i } from '19.c38ba2b0.chunk'
... etc
export const MyAPI = {
    function1: a.doSomething,
    function2: d.doSomething,
    ...
}

I've considered setting up webpack to produce a single bundled file with the filename that I'm after. I could call it MyAPI.js, and my problem would be solved. However, I'd be missing out on the benefits of chunking and cache busting. I want to use these features while still producing a nice, clean, single file with a known name (no hash) that can be used as an entry point to gain access to my API.

Took me a good long while, but I solved this after learning more about how webpack works. Each webpack bundle necessarily is made up of code that needs to run within the same synchronous context. That's probably a horrible way to describe it, but basically, the only way webpack is going to treat one file as a separate bundle is if there's an await import involved. So the solution looks like this:
// index.js
const { a } = await import('./abc')
const { d } = await import('./def')

export default {
    function1: a.doSomething,
    function2: d.doSomething
}

Since there's nothing in index.js that requires anything in abc or def right now, it's free to bundle index.js separately. Then, with everything else in a separate bundle, there's no need to point to the compiled bundle names. So then I add an exception to the naming system in webpack.config.js:
output: {
    filename: (pathData) => {
        return pathData.chunk.name?.includes('index') ? 'static/js/MyAPI.js' : 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
    }
}

So now the primary bundle is always called MyAPI.js, and webpack will automatically load the other bundles as needed. So I can use it like this:
import MyAPI from '/static/js/MyAPI.js'
MyAPI.a()
MyAPI.d()

I'm not sure this would work if I weren't outputting to ES6 modules. Specifically, I don't think I can export something that was imported with await import with other output library types. But it works great with ES6--webpack just makes sure that the dependencies are loaded before this bundle loads and executes.
